# invalid command name "55882440flash": while executing "55882440flash" ("after" script)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want to invoke one tkinter script another and FYI i'm able to do it but one issue i'm getting is for one particular framework which is nothing but so called login page. The Error is saying

```
invalid command name "55882440flash"
    while executing
"55882440flash"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "23964360flash"
    while executing
"23964360flash"
    ("after" script)"
```

This code i'm using for login page is : --

```
class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent,Text):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=Text, 
                              background="Red", foreground="white")
        self.label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.flash()

    def flash(self):
        bg = self.label.cget("background")
        fg = self.label.cget("foreground")
        self.label.configure(background=fg, foreground=bg)
        self.after(1200, self.flash)


def callback(*args):
    if args[1] == "username_lable":
        data['name'] = sv.get()
        print(data)
    elif args[1] == "password_lable":
        data['password'] = sv1.get()
        print(data)

def login_verify(*args):
    username1 = sv.get()
    password1 = sv1.get()
    # e_u.delete(0, END)
    # e_p.delete(0, END)

    list_of_files = os.listdir()
    if username1 in list_of_files:
        file1 = open(username1, "r")
        verify = file1.read().splitlines()
        if password1 in verify:
            try:
                root.destroy()
                import calculator as cp
                if __name__ == "__main__":
                    cp.main()
            except:
                print('fu')
        else:
            print('passsw')

    else:
        print('Fa')
```

any sort of help would be appreciate. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: actually i found out the issue...  Here in flash function is recursive soo it's getting failed here. but can u help me

Comment: Your `flash()` works fine.  I doubt that you have multiple instances of `Tk()`.  So once again, post the full traceback.